# How to set a possible date / time

Tags: single-word-requests

Say a friend wants to schedule a time to hang out, but I'm not sure when I'll be available, so we set a place-holder time that may be when we hang out or may not. What is this called? I feel like there's a word starting with 't' that works, but 'temporary time' doesn't sound right.

Eg "I'm not sure when I'm free so lets set a * time and we can see if we need to change it"

Comment: 'Tentative' is used in Callithumpian's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be thinking of "tentative".

"tentative"

> 2.unsure; uncertain; not definite or positive; hesitant
>  [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tentative)

A tentative meeting arrangement would be "pencilled in".

"pencil in"

> To give someone an appointment for a **tentative** or temporary time or
>   date

"pencil in"

> Why don't we just pencil in the dates we'd like, and we can go back
>   and change them if they're not available?  [Link](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pencil+in)